# javax validation not working on spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, javax.validation

I know there are already threads on this topic but unfortunately they don't help me, also because it seems that everything is OK at the configuration level.

I added the following dependency to the POM:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I'm using this version of Spring Boot:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.18</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

I have a DTO corresponding to the service request like this:

```java
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ObjectRequest implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @NotBlank(message = "Name field cant'be empty")
    private String name;

    private Map<String, String> data;
}
```

And this is the offending service that receives the object from before and, as the guide suggests, I used `@Valid`:

```java
@PostMapping("/add-object")
public ObjectResponse addObject(@Valid @RequestBody ObjectRequest request) {
    LOGGER.debug("BEGIN");
    ObjectResponse object = objectService.addObject(request);
    LOGGER.debug("END, object saved: [{}]", object);
    return object;
}
```

This is the call I make, below the JSON:

```json
{
   "name": "",
   "data": {
      "year": 2019,
      "price": 99.99
   }
}
```

Nothing happens! I mean, the call doesn't go through, but nothing logs, so it stops at the beginning. If instead I populate the name field, it works correctly.

I tried various things I found around `@Validated annotation` above the class or method, changing library versions (but I can't use Spring Boot 3.x), I don't know what to try anymore. Has anyone had a similar problem? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like the annotation is working as expected if it is not reaching your first log message when the ObjectRequest is missing a name. Do you have logging enabled for the library in question? You may need to reference it in logback.xml or log4j.xml file to get the logs appearing that you want

Comment: Strange, alternatively, I am using `import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;` which I believe is coming default with spring boot dependency, is working

Comment: @EthanConrad honestly in my logback.xml I don't have anything about javax.validation, but I noticed that from the call I simulate on Postman, which returns a 400 BAD_REQUEST error and reading around, some people in the RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler method had to override the handleMethodArgumentNotValid method to receive a sensible response. However, it doesn't seem like the natural behavior described by the guides....